# How to get child from Firebase nodes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been following this chat app tutorial with Swift, but now I want to be able to remove a post/message, so I want to be able to get to the specific child node to remove it, I've been trying like crazy a lot of things but nothing seems to work, I want to think I'm on the right path but I'm not pretty sure since I'm pretty new at coding.

I already got the Message Id, but in order to remove it I need to access to its parent.

```
@IBAction func buttonmessage(_ sender: Any) {

    let feedMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("feedMessages")
    print(feedMessageRef)

        }
    })
```

That's pretty much my code, I can access the feedMessages node, but I can't access the next node. And this is how my firebase structure looks like. I want to be able to get the "-5440543187537959509", and somehow delete it.

feedMessages

```
  -5440543187537959509

          -LnmwFyZeTYbqLJgH6uf

              date: 1567443980.238851

              from:"N3gVh9oXhPcrxeJzPWGjtqB0ka42"

              read: true

              text: "Testing with mando"

              to: "2LGYNCH4rFMJnKv3nQnvjcLyLhv1"

          -LnmwIQg6WeVAHxrWt0x

              date: 1567443990.295638

              from: "N3gVh9oXhPcrxeJzPWGjtqB0ka42"

              read: true

              text: "Huh?"

              to: "2LGYNCH4rFMJnKv3nQnvjcLyLhv1"
```

---

Ok, so I got this from reading the documentation and other Stack Overflow posts., now my code looks like this.

```
@IBAction func buttonmessage(_ sender: Any) {

        let feedMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("feedMessages").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

                for childSnap in snapshot.children.allObjects {

                    let snap = childSnap as! DataSnapshot
                    print(snap.key)
                    let changedText = (snap.value as? NSDictionary)?["text"] as? String ?? "ChangedText"
                    print(changedText)
                }
            }
}
```

[I managed to print the number that I wanted, which is a node from the firebase, but now I'm stuck on what's the next step to delete a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmQq.png)

Hope you guys can help me please, Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code you shared sets up a reference to the `feedMessages ` node in the database. It doesn't read anything from the database yet. You might want to read the documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events), or take the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/) to get started with that.